# Regex - Understanding negated character classes

Tags: regex

When I look at authoritative tutorial websites on regular expressions, the definition of negated character classes is always something like "matches all characters not in the list". However in this simple example : ["abc;xyz" -match "([^;]+)"](http://regex101.com/r/iH8jE7/1), I was hoping the match would be "abcxyz" but it isn't (match all characters that are not semicolons). So should the definition be "matches all characters not in the list but only up until it finds a character in that list"?

Comment: Try `"aba"` and regex `a+`. It has nothing to do with negated character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "match *any* character not in the list" or "match a character if and only if it is not in the list". The important thing to realize is that a character class will only ever match a single character.

In your example you match multiple characters because you add `+`. For any regex `r`, the regex `r+` matches one or more *consecutive* matches of `r`. Therefore `[^;]+` matches `abc`, because that is the largest, earliest substring of "abc;xyz" where each character matches `[^;]`.

Note that no regex will ever match a substring that does not exist. That is there is no regex that will match "abcxyz" in "abc;xyz" since "abcxyz" is not a substring of "abc;xyz".

Comment: So when using a quantifier it will only ever return a single consecutive substring? And is this not the case in regexp "replace" functions as examples like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/08/31/how-can-i-remove-all-the-non-alphabetic-characters-in-a-string.aspx) suggest one expression can match multiple substrings or even single characters.

Comment: @Lembasts A match of a regular expression will only ever be one consecutive substring. Depending on your language/regex library, there are functions that take a regex and return its first match, then there are functions that take a regex and return all non-overlapping matches. Likewise there are functions that replace a single match and then functions that replace every match. That simply depends on the function you're using.

Comment: Thanks. For another expanded explanation, I just found [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#longest_shortest)

Answer (score 0):

The Regex engine matches 'a'. Then it greedily matches 'b', followed by a greedy match of 'c'.

Then the Regex engine hits ';' and can go no further, so only 'abc' are matched.